# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

Hi I've been trying to code a UITableView Custom Cell and when I ran it I keep getting the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on this line of code:

```
let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell
```

My full code is below

In ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!

var arrayOfPersons: [Person] = [Person]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.setUpPersons()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setUpPersons()
{
    var person1 = Person(name: "Anna", number: 60, imageName: "testingimage.jpg")
    var person2 = Person(name: "Joes", number: 10, imageName: "testingimage2.jpg")

    arrayOfPersons.append(person1)
    arrayOfPersons.append(person2)

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
    return arrayOfPersons.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell



    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    let person = arrayOfPersons [indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(person.name, rightlabelInt: person.number, imageName: person.imageName)



    return cell

}

}
```

In CustomCell.Swift:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var leftlabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var rightlabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myimageview: UIImageView!


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)    }


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func setCell(leftlabelText: String, rightlabelInt: Int, imageName: String)
{
    self.leftlabel.text = leftlabelText
    self.rightlabel.text = String(rightlabelInt)
    self.myimageview.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}

}
```

And in Person.Swift:

```
import Foundation

class Person {

var name = "name"
var number = 0
var imageName = "blank"

init(name: String, number: Int, imageName: String)
{
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
    self.imageName = imageName
}
}
```

I am not sure what the error means or if I made a mistake somewhere. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Is your UITableView in Storyboard? Also if yes, do you have UITableViewCell with identifier as "Cell"?

Comment: Hi I just checked it again and I found I put the Cell in the wrong identifier >.< 
thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a class inheriting from UITextView. The solution turned out to be I needed to override all the init methods.

override init()
{ super.init() }

override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer)
{ super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer) }

override init(frame: CGRect)
{ super.init(frame: frame) }

required init(coder aCoder: NSCoder)
{ super.init(coder: aCoder) }